# On Monotonicity

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Given a convex function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Let $b$ be a positive number in $(0,1)$. Is $\frac{f(bx)}{f(x)}$ decreasing ? If not, can one provide a counter-example.

Comment: Differentiate $$\frac{f(bx)}{f(x)}$$ with respect to $x$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: How do we know that this function is differentiable?

Comment: Ok this is not given?

Comment: Lets assume $b>1.$ If $f(x) < 0 \in (0,a)$ and $f(x)> 0$ in $(a,1)$ then $\frac {f(bx)}{f(x)} > 0$ when $x\in (0,\frac ab), f(x) < 0$ when $x\in (\frac ab,a)$ and $f(x) > 0$ when $x\in(a,1)$